How to upgrade pyjwt version from 1.6 to 2.4 or above through linux shell?
This is in reference to resolve this CVE which is resulted due to old version of pyjwt - CVE-2022-29217
The pyjwt package present on my machine was 1.6.1 and it is not getting upgraded to >2.4 version.
I performed the below steps -
pip3 install PyJWT==2.4.0
pyjwt --version

And it still reflects the deprecated version after successful installation.
How can I set the version which I want it to use?
